# does glBindAttribLocation silently ignore names not found in a shader?

Tags: opengl, c, c++

Does `glBindAttribLocation` silently ignore names that are not found? For example, in a shader:

```
// Some vertex shader
in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
// ...
```

And in some set up code:

```
// While setting up shader
GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "normal");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 2, "color"); // What about this one?
glLinkProgram(program);
```

Comment: You can collect OpenGL errors and see what's silent and what's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a test for that and the short answer is openGL didn't return any error.

OpenGL documentation also states:

> glBindAttribLocation can be called before any vertex shader objects
>   are bound to the specified program object. **It is also permissible to
>   bind a generic attribute index to an attribute variable name that is
>   never used in a vertex shader.**
>
> If name was bound previously, that information is lost. Thus you
>   cannot bind one user-defined attribute variable to multiple indices,
>   but you can bind multiple user-defined attribute variables to the same
>   index.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I completely missed that sentence.